# Custom Theme template in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-theming

I know, if you want to check the names of the Display Output of the view page then we need to click on the Information Link near by Theme of Advance Theme of the view, it will list all the files.

After clicking on this, it will list.

**Display Output :** (View Machine name is **add_to_cart**)

views-view.tpl.php, views-view--add-to-cart.tpl.php, views-view--default.tpl.php, views-view--default.tpl.php, views-view--page.tpl.php, views-view--add-to-cart--page.tpl.php

So, could you please suggest which files should be best for creation of the Display Output template of the view page ?

Answer (score 1):

> If you want specific theming to your *page display* of `add_to_cart` view, then choose
>   to override `views-view--add-to-cart--page.tpl.php`.

I'll also want to add the importance of naming convention for templates, so that, next time, you can choose the template name yourself:

- **views-view.tpl.php**: called for every view.
- **views-view--add-to-cart.tpl.php**: called for only `add_to_cart` view.
- **views-view--default.tpl.php**: called for the display: `default`(*master display*) of every view.
- **views-view--page.tpl.php**: called for the display: `page` of every view.
- **views-view--add-to-cart--page.tpl.php**: called for the display: `page` of only `add_to_cart` view. (the specific suggestions are always last)

**Note:**

- **Template naming suggestion flow: general to specific.**
- **Also when you click the display output, you can copy the code for the template. This way you get all the variables that are available to you.**

Hope this help else comment for queries.

---

---

**Understanding how default, page comes in template names:**

- Within a view, you can create many displays as shown below.

[image]

- Each display has a Machine Name, for eg: *System display* has a machine name: `system_1`. So, a view with `system_1` display will be overrided using `views-view--system-1.tpl.php`. **Note**: the underscore('_') is replaced with hyphen('-'). The *by default view display* or *master display* in a view has a machine name: `default`.

[image]

Comment: thanks... but still confused for views-view--default.tpl.php,  views-view--page.tpl.php

Comment: @Parag Kuhikar, check the updated answer. added response to your query.